# Using Beautiful Soup to strip html tags from a string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Does anyone have some sample code that illustrates how to use Python's Beautiful Soup to strip all html tags, except some, from a string of text?

I want to strip all javascript and html tags everything except:

```
<a></a>
<b></b>
<i></i>
```

And also things like:

```
<a onclick=""></a>
```

Thanks for helping -- I couldn't find much on the internet for this purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import BeautifulSoup

doc = '''<html><head><title>Page title</title></head><body><p id="firstpara" align="center">This is <i>paragraph</i> <a onclick="">one</a>.<p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is <i>paragraph</i> <b>two</b>.</html>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(doc)

for tag in soup.recursiveChildGenerator():
    if isinstance(tag,BeautifulSoup.Tag) and tag.name in ('a','b','i'):
        print(tag)
```

yields

```
<i>paragraph</i>
<a onclick="">one</a>
<i>paragraph</i>
<b>two</b>
```

If you just want the text contents, you could change `print(tag)` to `print(tag.string)`.

If you want to remove an attribute like `onclick=""` from the `a` tag, you could do this:

```
if isinstance(tag,BeautifulSoup.Tag) and tag.name in ('a','b','i'):
    if tag.name=='a':
        del tag['onclick']
    print(tag)
```

Comment: Thank you -- any way to remove the onclick=""

Comment: add 'tag.attrs=[]' before printing to remove all attributes. If you need more control, tag.attrs is just a list of (name,value) pairs you can play with as you need.

Comment: This is probably an old version. I think "Tag" in bs4 is `bs4.element.Tag`

Comment: Also, this does not preserve the text between tags (e.g., "This is" in your example). The question is ambiguous on this, but I want all text content, and some of the tags (e.g., a, b, i in this example).