# How can I remove html tag with Python?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

My code is working. But the only thing it's also returning the HTML tags. Is there anything I can add to my FOR loop to strip the HTML code?

Here's my code below.

```py
addressNeeded = soup.find("h1", {"style": "font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit;"})
for x in addressNeeded:
    addressList.append(x)
```

the outcome is:

```
['\n', <label class="summary-list__label">
<span itemprop="streetAddress">95 Cooks Drive</span>
</label>, '\n', <span class="summary-list__label summary-list__label--small">
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Westside</span>,
                    <span itemprop="addressRegion">NY</span>
<span itemprop="postalCode">07663</span>
```

I thank you in advance!

Comment: Find returns only element but your outcome shows list of elements how this is possible.Post your relevant HTML and mentioned what expected output you are looking after?

Comment: Please, provide the html code you are dealing with and the result you want to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change your `print(x)` to `print(x.string)` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4424139/12448530) answer